# Class Not Found Android Support Design Widget NavigationView

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-navigationview

Good day, can you help me out. I got this error when compiling/running my code on an emulator. This is the sample tutorial I used to make. I used min Target API - 15 and compile the latest gradle 
`'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'`

http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html

Code Error:

*AndroidRuntime: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.eccp.projects.ecosavers.ecosavers/com.eccp.projects.ecosavers.ecosavers.activities.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: **Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView**
12-29 06:43:39.409 3448-3448/com.eccp.projects.ecosavers.ecosavers E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)*

E/AndroidRuntime:  **Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29: Binary XML file line #29: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView**

Here are my codes: `MainActivity.java`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //SET my own toolbar
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tool_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

    mNavigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation_view);

    mNavigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
            if (menuItem.isChecked()) menuItem.setChecked(false);
            else menuItem.setChecked(true);

            //Closing drawer on item click
            mDrawerlayout.closeDrawers();

            //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
            switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {


                //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                case R.id.events:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Inbox Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Eco_events fragment = new Eco_events();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame, fragment);
                    fragmentTransaction.commit();
                    return true;

                //  show a toast on click

                case R.id.activities:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Send Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                case R.id.spam:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Spam Selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Somethings Wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return true;

            }
        }
    });

    // Initializing Drawer Layout and ActionBarToggle
    mDrawerlayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerlayout, toolbar, R.string.drawerOpened, R.string.drawerOpened) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
        }
    };

    //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
    mDrawerlayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

    //calling sync state is
    mDrawerToggle.syncState();


}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

XML:`activity_main.xml`

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <include
        android:id="@+id/tool_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation_view"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer"
    /> </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: can you post the full stacktrace?

Comment: can you post apps build.gradle file?

Comment: @Raghunandan - what do you mean? The list of gradle that I used to compile?

Comment: @ankitaggarwal - I don't know to post the whole stack trace, I'm new. I only post that  segment where I find that is the error I need to fix. :( Do I need to edit and put the stack traced?

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:1.3.0' 

Gradle files.

Comment: @RoCk show full view of build.gradle

Comment: Check the logcat for the exception stack trace output. Follow "caused by" chain to the end and it will tell you what went wrong. My guess is that either @menu/drawer or @layout/header did not inflate properly. Check them out.

Answer (score 27):

**Follow this steps:**

1. Right Click on your `Project->Open Module Settings`.
2. Then open Dependencies Tab.
3. Click on + symbol then select Library Dependency.You will get an popup called Choose Library Dependency.
4. There Enter "com.android.support". Then click on search icon.

[image]

5. Now select the design library. and Click on OK.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for your concerns, I appreciate it. I found the answer for (my) this question at last.

Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.NavigationView #28 or #29

The solution that works for me, is that you must match your `support design library` and your support `AppCompat Library`. In the gradle module,

[image: Locate Gradle]

change the gradle version (Your desired library no. ) You can also find the latest gradle build in the link that I have given, but I suggest you check in your gradle module (The 2nd Picture, since they are first in updating the gradle build. Then in my gradle module - `compile: ...` has been highlighted , meaning there is a newer version, just change the no. e.g `24.0.0` compile if it is stable, not preview), in a mean time, mine is `23.1.1` .

-> [more gradle lib- gradleplease.appspot.com](http://gradleplease.appspot.com/)

`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'`

`compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'`

[image: Gradle Dependencies]

:) It works for me!

Observation (For me, As I changed/solved this error, the value `23.x.x`): if your `support-design` doesn't match with `AppCompat-lib` produces **#28** and if your `AppCompat` doesn't match the `support-design` produces **#29**. Just try, maybe I interchange the #.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because you need the Design Support Library.

Open SDK Manager and download Android Support Repository, than you can find the last version of the library here:

```
<android-sdk>/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/design/23.0.1/design-23.0.1.aar
```

Copy it in your libs directory then add the dependency to your build.gradle:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'android.support.design:design:23.0.1@aar'
}
```

Comment: this you mean? compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.0' 

I have already this lib. and gradle compiled already. :( 
.
I will search on youtube how to post this stack trace.